# strings from array contain common substring javascript

Tags: javascript

Here is my code:
I want to iterate through each pair of elements of the arrays, and if the strings in each pair contain one or more common substrings, `console.log(true)`, otherwise `console.log(false)`. 
So, output should be `true`, `false`, because "first" and "criss" have common substrings ("r", "i", "s")
Here is my code for now;

```
const a = ["first", "hi"];
const b = ["criss", "student"];

function commonSubstring(a, b) {
  a.forEach(a1 =>
    b.forEach(a2 => {
      for (i = 0; i < a1.length; i++) {
        if (a1.charAt(i) == a2.charAt(i)) {
          console.log(true");
        }
      }
    })
  );
}
commonSubstring(a, b);
```

Thanks for answers in advance!

Comment: Can you give an example of common substrings like first and student has st common in them. Is that what you mean or Is it the full string, or do you mean characters

Comment: You are only comparing the same character position in both test strings with `if (a1.charAt(i) == a2.charAt(i))`, so the only thing “first” and “criss” have in common would be the “s” at position 4 (3, if you start counting at 0.)

Answer (score 1):

You could take a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and check if a character is common.

```js
function common(a, b) {
    return [...a].some(Set.prototype.has, new Set(b));
}

var a = ["first", "hi"],
    b = ["criss", "student"],
    result = a.map((v, i) => common(v, b[i]));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const a = ["first", "hi"];
const b = ["criss", "student"];

function commonSubstring(a, b) {
  let result = [];
  a.forEach(a1 => {
    let found = false;
    b.forEach(a2 => {
      for (i = 0; i < a1.length; i++) {
        if (a1.charAt(i) == a2.charAt(i)) {
          //console.log(true);
          found = true;          
        }
      }
    })
    result.push(found);
    //console.log(found)
  });
 return result.join(',');
  
}
console.log(commonSubstring(a, b));
```

Comment: How to use return instead of console.log?

Comment: return not array of result but inline "true" and then "false"

Comment: You can join the array with ,. See the updated answer